# Looper.prepare Error on Device Not on Android Emulator

Tags: android

I trying to Make One App in which I will be Using CSV to restore to Sqlite Database .
This Code is working Fine on Android Emulator But Not Working On Device.
Please Help I am stuck very badly from last 3 days I am unable to figured out and tried many solution from Google but none of them are working.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


TextView lbl;
DBController controller;
Button btnimport;
ListView lv;
final Context context = this;
ListAdapter adapter;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;
public static final int requestcode = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    controller = new DBController(this);
    lbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtresulttext);
    btnimport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnupload);
    lv = getListView();
    btnimport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            Intent fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            fileintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            fileintent.setType("text/csv");
            try {

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(fileintent,"Open CSv"),requestcode);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                lbl.setText("No activity can handle picking a file. Showing alternatives.");
            }

        }
    });

    myList = controller.getAllProducts();
    if (myList.size() != 0) {
        ListView lv = getListView();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, myList,
                R.layout.v, new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}, new int[]{
                R.id.txtproductcompany, R.id.txtproductname, R.id.txtproductprice});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        lbl.setText("");

    }
        }

/** you were wrong here
 * R.id.txtjournalname, R.id.txtjournalissn, R.id.txtjournalif});
 in v.xml its
 R.id.txtproductcompany, R.id.txtproductname, R.id.txtproductprice});
 */

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {



    if (data == null)

    return;
           switch (requestCode) {

        case requestcode:

            String filepath = data.getData().getPath();
            controller = new DBController(getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = controller.getWritableDatabase();
            String tableName = "tbljournal";
            db.execSQL("delete from " + tableName);

            try {

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    try {
                        FileReader file = new FileReader(filepath);
                        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
                        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                        String line = "";
                        db.beginTransaction();

                        buffer.readLine();

                        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {


                            String[] str = line.split(",", 4);  // defining 3 columns with null or blank field //values acceptance

                            //Id, Company,Name,Price

                            String spinnerdata = str[0].toString();
                            String uniqueid = str[1].toString();
                            String melting = str[2].toString();
                            String weight = str[3].toString();

                            Log.e("data", spinnerdata);

                            contentValues.put("spinnerdata", spinnerdata);
                            contentValues.put("uniqueid", uniqueid);
                            contentValues.put("melting", melting);
                            contentValues.put("weight", weight);
                            db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);

                            lbl.setText("Successfully Updated Database.");

                        }
                        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

                        db.endTransaction();

                    }catch (SQLException e)
                    {
                        Log.e("Error",e.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {

                        if (db.inTransaction())
                        db.endTransaction();
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle(e.getMessage().toString() + "first");
                        d.show();
                        // db.endTransaction();
                    }
                } else {

                    if (db.inTransaction())

                    db.endTransaction();

                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);

                    d.setTitle("Only CSV files allowed");

                    d.show();
                                        }
                              } catch (Exception ex) {

                if (db.inTransaction())

                db.endTransaction();


                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);

                d.setTitle(ex.getMessage().toString() + "second");

                d.show();

                // db.endTransaction();

            }

    }


    myList = controller.getAllProducts();

    if (myList.size() != 0) {

        ListView lv = getListView();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, myList,

                R.layout.v, new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}, new int[]{
                R.id.txtproductcompany, R.id.txtproductname, R.id.txtproductprice});


        setListAdapter(adapter);

        lbl.setText("Data Imported");

    }
}
```

}

Below are LogCat

> 03-15 16:54:27.577 2559-2611/? E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>   03-15 16:54:36.185 2559-2620/com.example.arnav.androidcsv.demo E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>   03-15 16:54:46.556 2559-2763/com.example.arnav.androidcsv.demo E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Once I select CSV file from file Manager Nothing Happening it get Stuck .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

Comment: Go through this link to Write Question Correctly
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88541/how-to-write-code-in-a-question-or-answer